# Chamada cURL dentro de while

Tags: php, libcurl

Estou tentando fazer uma requisição `cURL` para cada linha retornada por uma query num banco de dados. O problema é que o meu programa morre logo após a primeira chamada `cURL`, e eu não faço ideia do por quê.

Pesquisando na internet, vi que o ideal seria separar a chamada `cURL` em uma função fora do while, mas isso não adiantou em nada. Simplificando muito do meu código, é isso que tenho até agora:

```php
<?php 
    include_once('config.php');
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    $stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM tabela");

    $array = array();
    if($stmt->execute()) {
        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $retorno = callCurl($row["info"]);

            $sql = "UPDATE tabela SET coluna1 = ?, coluna2 = ? WHERE id = ?";
            $stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute(array($retorno["lat"], $retorno["lng"], $row["id"]));

            array_push($array, $retorno);
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($array);

    function callCurl($info) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'meulink.com.br/script.php?param=' . $info);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        $retorno = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), TRUE);
        curl_close($ch);

        return $retorno;
    }
?>
```

Minha suspeita é de que o `curl_init` está quebrando na segunda iteração do while, mas não faço ideia do por que. Mesmo tentando usar `curl_error` não é retornado nada, o programa só morre mesmo.

Comment: Já verificou o arquivo de log de erros do servidor?

Comment: O erro não estava no cURL, mas sim na única coisa que ficou faltando testar: o `UPDATE`, derp.